# MySQL returning Different results on PHP and PHPMyadmin using same Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

1- **Here is simple php code retrieving MySQL rows**

[image]

2- **Here is return result of above code with query.**
[image]

3- But when I copy paste same query in phpmyadmin **100% sure on same database** It returns different result. See screenshot below; [image]

This blow up my mind, trying to figure out since two days but didn't find any solution. **What could be possible issue?**

Comment: Why did you post images? Where's your code? You have been here long enough to know this.

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. Besides, I can't read that tiny image text.

Comment: There is no *good* reason for that query to be using GROUP BY.

Comment: @Uueerdo but there are plenty of _less than good_ reasons. In particular, I have often seen a GROUP BY used where an ORDER BY would be more appropriate. Unfortunately, older versions of MySQL would let you do that and get away with it.

Comment: actually nothing to do with queries and code, I am mistaken with some settings or information about mysql. Simple query is what same query gives different results on different platforum. I am expecting answer like first answer is provide, but I don't understand that either :(

Comment: btw, I am actually trying get cheapest package from each destination

Answer (score 1):

Your query is an aggregation query that has `group by t.destination`.

However, it selects a bunch of other columns that are not arguments to aggregation functions.  There is no evidence that they are functionally dependent on `t.destination` either.

Happily, such sloppiness generates a syntax error on most databases.  Happily, it generates a syntax error in the more recent versions of MySQL (using the default settings).  Unhappily. some people write such queries on older versions of MySQL (or change the flag that controls this) . . . and then wonder why the code doesn't work as expected.

The extra values come from an *indeterminate* matching row within each group.  Running the query at different times might result in different values for those "bare" columns.  Running with different settings (or different sources) also might also result in different results.

Comment: Good call. I've made the same mistake. I would suggest changing the "GROUP BY colA ORDER BY colB" to "ORDER BY colA, colB". I suspect this is the reason the GROUP BY was added to the query in the first place.

Comment: @UncaAlby it will returns all the rows, I want to show cheapest package from each destination.

Comment: @WasimA. . . . This answers why the results are different -- which is what this question asks.  If you want help with your actual problem, ask a *new* question.

Comment: Why would this be *anonymously* downvoted?  Does someone actually disagree with it?

Comment: @WasimA. Then you need to add an aggregate function to the query, something like (but probably not exactly like), "SELECT id,destination, **MIN(destination_price)** FROM table **GROUP BY** destination"

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was probably down-voted because somebody thinks the question *"is not worthy"*. And so therefore, neither is the answer. I'll admit the images were a bit off-putting, but it is a fair question, and the answer is good. But somebody has voted, and outside of getting all our friends involved to mob the vote back up again, there's little we can do about it.

Comment: SMH.. obviously @GordonLinoff needs some more reputation to earn somebody's trust!  Now I don't feel so bad about the drive-by down-voters nabbing me on occasion :p